# Скопировать элемент из массива объектов в отдельный объект

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, объекты

Есть класс integer, содержащий поле int integer, есть массив integer *intar[10], где в каждый элемент, тобишь объект, записаны значения переданные через конструктор инициализации. Также есть отдельный объект newInteger. Задача состоит в том что нужно как-то написать оператор, который присваивает новому объекту значения из выбранного элемента массива intar

```
class integer
{
 private:
  int intgr; //здесь поле
 public:
  integer(int a):intgr(a) //конструктор с аргументами
  {}
  integer() //пустой конструктор
  {}
  void print()//пишем на экран
  {
   cout << integer << endl;
  }
}
int main()
{
 integer *intar[10]; //массив объектов класса
 integer newInteger; //объект сам по себе
 for(int a=0;a<10;++a)
 {
  intar[a]=new integer(a); //присваивание значения всем объектам в массиве
 }
 newInteger=intar[4]; //попытка скопировать, не работает
```

Последняя строчка не работает, вижла в консоли компиляции пишет следующее:

> error C2679: бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий правый
> операнд типа "integer *" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
>
> note: может быть "integer &integer::operator =(integer &&)"
>
> note: или       "integer &integer::operator =(const integer &)"
>
> note: при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(integer, integer *)"

Следуя подсказкам вижлы, я попытался написать конструктор присваивания такой:

```
integer &integer::operator=(integer &&)
{
 return *this;
}
```

И такой:

```
integer &integer::operator=(const integer &iny)
{
 return *this;
}
```

Разумеется это не дало результата

Как должен выглядеть конструктор присваивания или копирования? Тело конструктора соображу, а вот как оно должно выглядеть не понимаю. Гугл традиционно ничего не знает, либо даёт темы с простым копированием из объекта в объект не учитывая, что первый в массиве

Comment: `intar[4]` - имеет тип указателя на объект `integer *`. А при добавлении звёздочки будет ссылка : `*(intar[4])` -> `integer &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на исправленный код:

```
class integer
{
    private:
        int intgr; //здесь поле
        public:
            integer(int a):intgr(a) //конструктор с аргументами
            {}
            integer() //пустой конструктор
            {}
            void print()//пишем на экран
            {
                cout << intgr << endl;
            }
};

int main()
{
    integer *intar[10]; //массив УКАЗАТЕЛЕЙ на объекты класса
    integer newInteger; //объект сам по себе
    for(int a=0;a<10;++a)
    {
        intar[a]=new integer(a); //СОЗДАНИЕ и присваивание значения всем объектам в массиве
    }
    newInteger=*intar[4]; //попытка скопировать, работает

    newInteger.print();

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оказывается нужно было обозначить как указатель? Странно что я в гугле не нашёл такой очевидной вещи